# Getting <select>'s selected options text, not values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

How can one get the selected option's name's `One` and `Two` rather than the options values `1` and `2`.

`$("select").val()` would return the array `["1", "2"]`, which is undesired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
var arr = $("select option[selected]").map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ESRQR/

Comment: Brilliant and concise answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=$("select option[selected]").text();
```

this will give you the `text` of the selected option instead of its `value`

[click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TBa8s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

var selected = $('select option:selected').text();

alert(selected);

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5rgju/5/